# R writexl::write_xlsx no usa la ruta que le indico

Tags: r

Contexto. Trato de correr el siguiente código:

```
library(writexl)

path_to_save <- "D:\\path\\to\\save\\file.xlsx"

df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:4, col2 = letters[1:4])

writexl::write_xlsx(df, path = path_to_save)
```

Que me arroja este error:

```
[ERROR] workbook_close(): Error creating 'D:\path\to\working\directory\D:\path\to\save\file.xlsx'. System error = No such file or directory
Error: Error in libxlsxwriter: 'Error creating output xlsx file. Usually a permissions error.'
```

Entiendo que writexl trata de escribir en una ruta que sale de concatenar el path al working directory con el path donde quiero que guarde el archivo. Duré un par de horas buscando soluciones, sin éxito.

Mi versión de R es 4.2.1, RStudio 2023.06.0 Build 421 y writexl 1.4.2 en Windows 10

Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: Según la documentación `path a file name to write to` o sea, es la ruta del archivo, tiene que ser una ruta valida, y esto: `D:\path\to\working\directory\D:\path\to\save\file.xlsx` no parece ser una ruta válida.